# How to move span to left with margin auto Css angular 4

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

Hi I have some issue regarding Css and I have not been able to do it.
[image]

how to move those numbers which are highlighted to left with names.
I have tried flex direction margin auto etc but I cannot get desired result.

**here is my html code**

```
<section class="favorites">
<div class="category" *ngFor="let category of categoryKeys">
<div class="sub-header">{{category}}</div>
<app-custom-accordion [closeOthers]="true">
  <ngb-panel [disabled]="panel.Tests.length === 0" *ngFor="let panel of testSelectionSession.FavoritesByCategory[category]"
             id="{{panel.Id}}" [title] = "panel.Name">
    <ng-template ngbPanelTitle>
      <span class="test-length" style=""> {{ '(' + panel.Tests.length + ')'}}</span>
      <div class="action-items">
        <span class="icon-set" [ngClass]="{'same-day-2x': isSameDay(panel.Code), 'next-day-2x': isNextDay(panel.Code)}"></span>
        <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" [name]="panel.Id + '-' + panel.Moniker" [ngModel]="checkAllTestsSelected(panel)"
            (ngModelChange)="onPanelCheckboxUpdate($event, panel)" [id]="panel.Id + '-' + panel.Moniker">
          <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
        </label>
      </div>
    </ng-template>
  </ngb-panel>
</app-custom-accordion>
```

**I am trying to move this tag to left**

```
<span class="test-length" style=""> {{ '(' + panel.Tests.length + ')'}}</span>
```

can someone help me regarding this issue?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO Usman, please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What's your HTML & CSS for this particular section of your site ? Update your post with a code snippet or at least a jsfiddle.

Comment: ok sure i will update this

Comment: What's your CSS ? Create a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) if it's easier for you.

Comment: @Jake have not applied any css yet. dont know what to add

Comment: Have you tried to move the `.test-length` span before the title of your content ?

Comment: it does not show anything. code is complex i cannot be able to solve it. there is another component in this code app-custom-accordion

Comment: Then we're back to square one, please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: the only way i am doing this because i have to highlight tests.length to bold 
otherwise i can write it like this as well  [title] = "panel.Name + '(' + panel.Tests.length + ')'" 
if there is any way to bold half of title that would be great @Jake

Comment: Set this particular item to `font-weight: bold` using CSS or use `<strong>content</strong>` to set your content to bold.

Comment: how in title i cannot add any css or tag

Comment: Like so : `<span class="test-length" style=""><strong>{{ '(' + panel.Tests.length + ')'}}</strong></span>` ...

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution will be including

```
'(' + panel.Tests.length + ')'
```

in the panel title:

```
  <ngb-panel [disabled]="panel.Tests.length === 0" *ngFor="let panel of testSelectionSession.FavoritesByCategory[category]"
             id="{{panel.Id}}" [title] = "panel.Name + '(' + panel.Tests.length + ')'">
```

The component seriously resembles a table, making contents of a separate column float left seems hard to achieve. Although I'm not familiar with `ngb-panel`.

Comment: i tried that but i have to apply bold property too in this test.length that is why i cannot write it in title. if there is any property to just add bold to half title that will be great. @mbojko